# как рисовать график в цикле for

Tags: python, pandas, график, визуализация

Дано:

- jupyterlab
- dataframe с двумя столбцами:

1. дата
2. числа (z)

в цикле for перебираю dataframe построчно и хочу рисовать график, где ось x - это даты из столбца, а ось y - это значения функции f(z), которые вычисляются на каждой итерации цикла.
хочу чтобы при каждой итерации цикла на графике добавлялась новая точка.

Comment: Посмотрите вот это https://github.com/kimfetti/Videos/blob/master/ipywidgets/03_quick_animation.ipynb Та часть, где `widgets.Play` используется

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали никаких подробностей о природе ваших данных и о том как вычисляются значения неизвестной нам функции `f(z)` и почему эти вычисления нужно делать в цикле, а не векторным способом. Поэтому в своем ответе я дам *общие* рекомендации:

1. гораздо проще, быстрее и удобнее рисовать график не по отдельным точкам, а сразу указав все точки по оси `X` и по оси `Y`. И делать это удобнее всего [методами Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html):

```
df.plot(x="date_column_name", y="y_column_name")
```

2. Т.к. оперировать лучше сразу векторами, то следует сначала подготовить столбец со значениями функции `f(z)`, которые вы хотите отобразить на графике:

```
df["y"] = f(df["z"]) # здесь предполагается, что функция `f(z)` умеет работать с вектором данных и возвращать вектор значений.
```

Comment: знаю и про вектора и отрисовку сразу, но вот именно в этой части кода есть перебор по строкам, он там необходим и хочется график строить в цикле. :(